# Автозамена на спецсимволы

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Есть небольшое веб приложение для обмена сообщениями, вроде форума...
Когда пользователь пишет своё сообщение, то оно попадает в бд, затем другие пользователи могут это сообщение прочесть... В сообщении, которое вводит пользователь, есть возможность менять размер шрифта, цвет и т.д. в результате чего, в базу попадает сообщение в виде: `<font color="#ffff00">1231sdasd</font><b style=""><font color="#ffff00">asdasd</font></b>`. При запросе этого сообщения, контроллер его именно в таком виде и отдаёт, затем я его вставляю в страничку с помощью Thymeleaf. Проблема заключается в том, что на страничке отображаются не цветные слова, а сами теги, так как `<` и `>` автоматический заменяются на `&lt;` и `&gt;`. Как спастись от замены тегов на спецсимволы?)

Comment: это защита от xss. Сегодня юзер цвет указал, завтра скрипт напишет на JS или фрейм подставит, что будете делать?

Comment: @tym32167 да, проблемка... Но я знаю, что на многих форумах практикуется такое как изменение цвета и размера шрифтов и сообщениях. Как тогда это реализовать? Есть варианты?) Или новую тему нужно создавать с этим вопросом?)

Comment: нет там никакой защиты, можно и скрипт засунуть с бесконечным выводом чего нибудь и будет весело )) . th:utext - для записи в бд, th:text - для вывода и все должно работать

Comment: я не знаю ни java, ни spring, но, мне кажется, должны быть специальные модули для такого или, например, поддержка форматирования, которая не относится к HTML (например, на этом сайте есть поддержка markdown, потому тут можно и **жирным** выделять, и *курсивом*), но вот про изменение цвета я не в курсе.

Comment: @Алексейг , вот как раз `<tag th:text="${var}"></tag>` и `<tag>[[${var}]]</tag>` заменяют теги на спецсимволы.

Comment: что такое <tag>? не встречал. Добавляете в базу как?  th:utext?

Comment: @Алексейг, `<tag>` - имеется ввиду любой тег(например `<div>` или `<span>`). Добавление в базу обычное: пользователь вводит сообщение в `<textarea>`, с него формой летит всё на контроллер и добавляется в базу. Про `th:utext` не совсем понятно...

Comment: пардон, напутал - вывод вашего сообщения сделайте не th:text, а  th:utext. Гугл перевод документации: "Если мы хотим, чтобы Thymeleaf уважал наши теги XHTML и не экранировал их, нам придется использовать другой атрибут: th:utext(для «неэкранированного текста»)"

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос следующим образом:
Полученные сообщения вывожу с помощью `<tag th:utext="${myvar}"></tag>`, так как `th:utext` не экранирует теги на выходе. А перед записью в базе я проверяю само сообщение небольшой самодельной защитой:

`private String xssSecurity(String message) {
        char[] chars = message.toCharArray();
        boolean closeTag = false;
        for (int i = 0, j; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (chars[i] == '<') {
                System.out.println(chars.length);
                for (j = i; j < chars.length; j++) {
                    char h = chars[j];
                    if (chars[j] == ' ' || chars[j] == '>') {
                        String tag = message.substring(i + 1, j);
                        System.out.println(tag);
                        if (tag.matches("/?b") || tag.matches("/?font") || tag.matches("/?i")) {
                            closeTag = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            chars[i] = '•';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (chars[i] == '>') {
                if (!closeAccept) {
                    chars[i] = '·';
                } else {
                    closeTag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chars).replaceAll("·", "&gt;").replaceAll("•", "&lt;");
    }`

В итоге я получаю сообщение со всеми экранированными тегами, кроме разрешенных(в моём случае это `b`, `i` и `font`).